# Массовый импорт postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите, можно ли как нибудь массово импортировать .sql файлы таблиц в базу данных postgresql ?

А то выходит только по одной, что очень долго. Использую команду \i filename.sql

Windows + openserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это разовая операция то можно:

**Вариант 1**

1. Сгенерировать кучу команд в любом блокноте ( sublime, notepad++, ... )
2. вставить команды в консоль

**Вариант 2**

Если у тебя Linux

```
ls |grep sql|xargs -I {} psql -U USER_NAME -d DATA_BASE_NAME -f {}
```

Если у тебя windows:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b C:\sql_files') do psql -U USER_NAME -d DATA_BASE_NAME -f %f
```

Comment: у меня windows + Open Server. Через консоль пробовал что-то вроде цикла (нагуглил) for f in *.sql do \i $f done. В ошибке говорит, что некорректный путь, хотя нахожусь внутри нужного каталога. Может исходя из этого подскажете

Comment: перейти в папку с sql файлами ( для примера C:\sql_files ) и в cmd консоли выполнить команду.

ну и заменить имя пользователя и бд ))


```for /f %f in ('dir /b C:\sql_files') do psql -U USER_NAME -d DATA_BASE_NAME -f %f```

Comment: по поводу вашего варианта for f in *.sql do \i $f done, с ходу не подскажу, но скорее всего что -то не так с правами или вы не там находитесь  на самом деле.
можно попробовать явно указать путь к файлами

как пример ( если не путаю ничего ):
```for f in *.sql do \i С:\sql_files\$f done```. Возможно при этом будет проблема с правами( а может и не будет )

Comment: у вас всё получилось? ))))

Comment: не пробовал, но за варианты спасибо! Может кому-то понадобятся в будущем )